# Foundational question: to nonunitial commutative rings correspond to schemes?

Tags: schemes

Affine schemes correspond to unitial commutative rings, of course.

Further, let us draw upon the Gelfand correspondence, where commutative $C^*$-algebras are dual to compact hausdorff spaces. If we lax the condition that these $C^*$-algebras be unitial, then then the correspondence is with locally compact hausdorff spaces instead. The functionals on a locally compact hausdorff space are required to have compact support.

My question:

> Is there a way of viewing general schemes as corresponding to unitless rings, in a way extending the correspondence between rings and affine schemes?

The proposed correspondence would be this: write a scheme $X$ as a filtered colimit of affine schemes $\text{colim}_I X_i$. Then consider $\text{lim}_I \mathcal{O}_{X_i}(X_i)$ in the category of $\textit{unitless}$ rings.

I have slight suspicions that this approach works, given that projective space has simply a field as its global sections.

Perhaps there is some necessary condition on the maps, such as locally unit preserving. And for that matter, what is the new definition of prime ideal? It would seem that we want all primes to be proper still, but usually that is related to $1 \notin \mathfrak{p}$, so this may change.

But to be clear what would change is that now we consider sheaves in nonunitial commutative rings, and we make a sheaf out of such rings on their spectrum of primes (let's try the same definition, and tweak if we have to) all spaces are required to be affine. There should be a canonical projection of sheaves of nonunitial rings from the new structure sheaf to the usual structure sheaf. For projective space, this would be the projection $\text{limit} \mathcal{O}_{X_i}(X_i) \rightarrow k$, where this limit is taken of nonunitial rings.

Comment: A ring $R$ has local units if it is a filtered colimit of unital rings (but with non-unit preserving maps).  Equivalently, for each finite subset $F$ of $R$, there is an idempotent $e$ with $F\subseteq eRe$.  A result of Pierce shows that commutative von Neumann regular rings are rings of global sections of sheaves of fields on a profinite space.  If you just require the von Neumann regular ring to have local units, then you can realize the ring as the compactly supported global sections of a sheaf of rings on a locally compact totally disconnected Hausdorff space.

Comment: So maybe something similar where you have to put restrictions on supports can work in some setting.  BTW for Gelfand's theorem, in the non-unital case you use functions vanishing at infinity.  If you just use compact support you are not complete.